# Couldn't find Plan without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with my controller subscriptions. 
I try to create a form using Stripe for payments. 
I created 3 plans on seeds.rb, I can index and show them with an ID but I don't know how to transpose the id of plans/show to subscription/new.

Here's my subscription_controller.rb :

```
require "stripe"
skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token


def new
    @titre = "Abonnement"
    @subscription = Subscription.new params[:subscription]

    @plan = Plan.find params[:subscription][:plan_id]
    if @subscription.save_with_payment
        flash[:success] = 'Félicitations ! Vous êtes maintenant abonné à notre service.'
        redirect_to root_path
        else
        flash.now[:error] = "Erreur lors de la crétion de votre formule d'abonnement"
        render template: 'plans/show'
    end
end

def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
end

private

def subscription_params
    params.require(:registration).permit(:lastname, :email, :firstname, :company, :city, :country, :adress, :postalcode)
end
```

Here's my plan_controller.rb :

```
require "stripe"
before_action :set_plan, only: [:show]
skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token

def index
    @plans = Plan.all
end

def show
end
```

my subscription model :

```
belongs_to :plan
belongs_to :user

validates_presence_of :plan_id
validates_presence_of :email

attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

def save_with_payment
    if valid?
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
        self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
        self.next_bill_on          = Date.parse customer.next_recurring_charge.date
        save!
    end
    rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    logger.error "Erreur Stripe lors de la création du profil client : #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "Il y a eu un problème lors du paiement avec votre carte."
    false
end
```

and my registration/new.html.erb :

```
<h1>Signing up for "<%= @registration.plan.name %>"</h1>
<h2><%= number_to_currency @registration.plan.price %></h2>

<%= form_for @registration do |f| %>
 <% if @registration.errors.any? %>
   <div class="error_messages">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@registration.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this subscription from being saved:</h2>
  <ul>
  <% @registration.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<%= f.hidden_field :plan_id %>

<%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<% if @registration.stripe_card_token.present? %>
Credit card has been provided.
<% else %>
<div class="field">
  <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
  <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
  <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
</div>
<% end %>
<div id="stripe_error">
  <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Subscribe" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

If someone could give me a track him I would be very grateful :)

Thanks

Comment: have you tried saving the id in the session?

Comment: No but this append before the creation of a customer, so I'm not sure I want to save it in the session..

Comment: The other option is to save the value in params, both of the approaches is used to pass variable values between actions and controllers